# Vanilla 1.8 detect new player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

In vanilla 1.8 using command blocks, is it possible to change a player's spawn point after they first join a server?

When a player first joins a server they are in location "A"
When they press a button to leave the spawn point (or use any other trigger) they are sent to location "B" 
If they die after leaving the spawn they will respawn in location "B"

No mods or plugins
1.8 Vanilla
McEdit map editing is OK

Comment: Is moving worldspawn an option, or do you use the spawn-chunks for keeping some farms running?

Comment: Moving the worldspawn each time is not an option, but moving it to build the Redstone and command blocks for the spawn thing should be fine. Basicly there is no set spawn point as of yet, and the map may be reset or changed completely before the server goes public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new scoreboard objective "new"

```
/scoreboard objectives add new dummy
```

Make the world spawn where you want the non-new players to spawn. Put a pressure plate under them (So they spawn on a pressure plate) that triggers a command block with the command

```
testfor @p[score_new_min=1,score_new=1]
```

This will test for any player with a score of one in "new"
Make that command block connect to a comparator that connects to another command block with the command

```
tp @p[score_new_min=1,score_new=1] x y z
```

Where x, y, and z are the coordinates of the place you want new players to spawn.

If you are going to have a lot of new players spawning at once however, this system might teleport the wrong new player. In that case, do this system except make the pressure plate in front of where they spawn, and make it their only option to walk over that pressure plate to get to the main spawn room.

Comment: This looks like it should work exactly how I need it to. One question though, if I were to replace the test for command from "@p" to "@a[r=3]" would it still work? I'll see about testing it, but I thought I'd ask, just in case you already have an answer.

Comment: Worldspawn spawns you somewhere in a 20 block radius (xz) around the coordinates you set it to (an on the highest block). You can't use a single pressure plate for this. Also, you never set the scoreboard objective to anything and the testfor is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where using `stat` objectives on a scoreboard comes in handy, since it is impossible to detect players who don't have a score (i.e. a score of NULL, which is different from a score of 0!). `stat` objectives increase automatically depending on player actions, making them ideal for this. Set up a `timePlayed` objective like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add timePlayed stat.playOneMinute
```

Contrary to the name, `playOneMinute` objectives increase at every game tick (making the value 1200 after one minute). You can use this objective to detect new players using `@a[score_timePlayed=1]`.

To teleport new Players to a fixed point, set up a setblock clock and have it run

```
/tp @a[score_timePlayed=1] x y z
```

where `x y z` are the coordinates of your spawn.

Credit goes to [/u/Boxfigs](http://www.reddit.com/user/Boxfigs) on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2kwyxv/help_with_selectors/clpi4rf).

---

Should you want to re-declare an existing player as new (e.g. for testing), you can use

```
scoreboard players reset P timePlayed
```

where `P` is any valid target selector.