# What command do I use in minecraft for setting people spawn when they spawn on a map I create? Because I am host

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What command do I use to make everyone spawn at one place? because I am making a map and I don't know how to make everyone spawn at one place, the rule place.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers you need can be found [on the Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

---

The `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>` command sets the spawn for any new players who join said world, or if they do not have a spawnpoint already.

The `/spawnpoint [user] <x> <y> <z>` command sets the spawn point for a specific player.

---

If you'd need a specific point (similar to Essentials' `/spawn` command) to spawn (presuming that everybody's mainly in Survival), I'd recommend making a spawn platform with a command block clock that teleports anyone on that platform to the rule room and set the `/setworldspawn` location to that platform.

This way, new players are captured by the `/tp` clock (on the platform) and are teleported straight to the rule room (a static co-ordinate).

And if you'd like to force all players' spawnpoint (only works with existing players), run a clock with `/spawnpoint @a <Location>`.

Comment: Just curious does setworldspawn lock the spawn to the specific spot unlike the natural world spawn?

Comment: It literally changes world spawn, and from experience, it doesn't lock to a spot.

Comment: Normally the world spawn allows players to spawn in an range, does setworldspawn still do that or it forces the players to spawn on the block?

Comment: The behavior of spawn point depends on player's game mode. If your server's default gamemode is **Adventure**, new players will spawn at exact coordinates, unconditionally. Players in **Survival** mode and higher will spawn randomly in a certain range, and on topmost block for given horizontal coords.

Comment: @OrcJMR Actually, couldn't you just use a clock with `/setspawnpoint @a <Location>`?

Comment: @aytimothy Yes, the "spawn trap" you have described seems to be a nice solution for a non-Adventure server

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to use a `stat.playOneMinute` objective to identify the new players, as indicated in this [shameless plug](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/223603/74333) of mine.

Comment: Note that the range at which the player spawns (disregarding the exact location with adventure) in singleplayer is always a 20x20 square, offset to the north-west. But in multiplayer it is dependent on the `spawn-protection` setting in server.properties. The lowest the range can be is 10x10, but otherwise it can be as large as the playable world, so a platform may not work if the map is intended for multiplayer.

Answer (score -3):

```
/setworldspawn ~0 ~0 ~0
```

The "~0"s state that you want something set to your exact standing position. If you want something precise, such as for example, if you were making an *illuminati map* then do something like

```
 /setworldspawn ~3 ~3 ~3
```

Happy MineCrafting, hope this helps.

Comment: Why does "Illuminati" need a spawn that is 3 meters east, south and above the player?

Comment: Because there are 3 sides to a triangle my fellow non illu- I mean player. >:),

Comment: But won't ~200 ~200 ~200 give an even bigger and badder, while equally equilateral triangle? :-)

Comment: The real question is, where is Doc when you need him, this is heavy...